# Refresh particular div only once after success response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

Below is the `div` which I need to refresh on response of an AJAX request.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 avatar">
    <a title="Change Profile Picture" onclick="changeprofile()">
        <img alt="Profile photo" class="" src="http://example.com/service/getUserImage/123/256">        
    </a>
</div>
```

```js
function updateprofilepic() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/profile",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(msg1) {
        toastr.success(msg1);
        // here i want to refersh that div.
    });
}
```

Is there any way to refresh that with the same content because my image is fetching from a third party so no need to change the content. Simply I want to refresh that div which shows the new content automatically.

Comment: So you just want to reload the `img` element within the `div`, is that correct?

Comment: yes i want to reload only image

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Do you have a idea how?